# Dropdown box in flask not showing values

Tags: python, flask, db2

I'm bringing table values data from ibm_db to flask.

```
@app.route("/unplanned_outage", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def unplanned_outage():
    global conn
    ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=bludb;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=1234;SECURITY=SSL;;UID=uid;PWD=pwd;", '', '')
    conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(ibm_db_conn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    select="select * from tools"
    cur.execute(select)
    tools = cur.fetchall()
    print("Query results:\n")
    print(tools,end="\n")
    cur.close()
    return render_template(r'page.html', tools=tools)
```

The database is getting connected and printing the query results in terminal as expected.
I'm getting this values to html dropdown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form class="row g-3" style="margin: auto; width: 80%;  padding: 30px;">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label for="inputState1" class="form-label">Tools</label>
            <select id="inputState1" class="form-select">
              <option selected></option>
              {% for row in tools %}
              <option value='{{row.id}}'>{{row.tools}}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But these values are not being displayed in html page.

[dropdown looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myeg2.png)

There is no error message. Please help on how i can get these values to be rendered in html. Thanks much!

Edit:
As requested this is the output of print statement. It is printing the list of dicts in terminal.
[print output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzDE5.png)

I'm new to flask, so please bear with me. Should i be adding any js code so that it helps flask to render into html?

Comment: Can you show the output of print(tools). Does it show a list of dicts with keys ‘id’ and ‘tools’?

Comment: @EAW i have added the image of the print output in the question summary. please find it there. as expected the output is being printed in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you @EAW, you helped me to think more about the output!

Answer (score 0):

So when i sent static values from flask to HTML with a single string and then a list, it displayed on the html page.

I realized a single column  without id from table was printing as tuples in a list as
[('ABC',), ('DEF',), ('GHI',)]

so i tried a workaround and tried to tune them in a list

```
tools1=[]
for x in tools:
    tools1.append(''.join(x))
print(tools1)
```

which then gave me the output as
['ABC','DEF','GHI']

When i passed them into HTML, it displayed fine in the dropdown box.